# ERRO Java: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual

Tags: java, hibernate

Sou novo em Java e estou tendo dificuldades para mostrar na página um grid com dados de uma tabela do banco de dados. Estou usando java + hibernate + JSF 2 + tomcat 8. Quando executo minha página xhtml apresenta o erro abaixo. O problema está no form lista do xhtml, pois o form edição executa sem problemas.Estou a um bom tempo tentando resolver e não consigo evoluir.

**Erro**

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual abr 11, 2016 11:11:04 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/]
>   threw exception [null] with root cause javax.servlet.ServletException

**Código do Filtro**

```
@Override

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletFilter, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

try { //trata exceção caso dê alguma coisa errada
    /*O processamento inicial passa por este método*/
    this.sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction(); //pega a sessão corrente e inicia uma transação
    chain.doFilter(servletFilter, servletResponse); //passa o filter e o response para o filter chain
    this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit(); //dá um comite na transação aberta acima
    this.sf.getCurrentSession().close(); //fecha sessão corrente

} catch (Throwable ex) {
    try { // trata o rollback
        //verifica o status da transação e se estiver ativa dá um rollback 
        System.out.println("Deu exceção 1: " + ex);
        if (this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE) {
            this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();    
        }       
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Deu exceção 2: " + t);
        t.printStackTrace(); //joga a exceção do rollback e imprime na tela
    }
    throw new ServletException(); /*Joga a exceção*/
}
}
```

**Código do XHTML**

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="pageTitle">Cidade</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="pageHeader">Cadastro de Cidades</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
     <h:form id="edicao">
     <h:messages /> <!-- viabiliza as mensagens na tela -->
         <h:panelGrid columns = "2">
             <h:outputLabel value="Nome" />
             <h:inputText value="#{cidadeBean.cidadeSelecionado.nome}" />

             <h:outputLabel value="Estado" />
             <h:inputText value="#{cidadeBean.cidadeSelecionado.estado}" />

         </h:panelGrid>
         <h:commandButton action="#{cidadeBean.salvar}" value="Salvar" />

     </h:form> 

     <h:form id="lista"> 
         <h:messages />
        <h:dataTable value="#{cidadeBean.lista}" var="cidade" border = "1">
            <f:facet name="header">Listagem de Cidades</f:facet>

            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
            #{cidade.nome} 
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Estado</f:facet>
             #{cidade.estado} 
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
     </h:form>  

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Código do CidadeBean**

```
package oneTrade.cidade;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean(name = "cidadeBean")
@RequestScoped //vai ser do tipo request pois só vai enviar o formulário
public class CidadeBean {

private Cidade cidadeSelecionado = new Cidade();
private List<Cidade> lista = null;

public void salvar(){
  CidadeRN cidadeRN = new CidadeRN();
  cidadeRN.salvar(cidadeSelecionado);

  FacesMessage faces = new FacesMessage("Cidade Cadastrada com sucesso");
  FacesContext contexto = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  contexto.addMessage(null, faces);
}

public Cidade getCidadeSelecionado() {
  return cidadeSelecionado;
}

public void setCidadeSelecionado(Cidade cidadeSelecionado) {
  this.cidadeSelecionado = cidadeSelecionado;
}

public List<Cidade> getLista() {

  CidadeRN cidadeRN = new CidadeRN();
  if (lista == null){
    lista = cidadeRN.listar();
   }
    return lista;
 }
}
```

**Código - CidadeDAOHibernate.java**

```
package oneTrade.cidade;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class CidadeDAOHibernate implements CidadeDAO {

private Session sessao;



public Session getSessao() {
    return sessao;
}


public void setSessao(Session sessao) {
    this.sessao = sessao;
}


@Override
public void salvar(Cidade cidade) {
    this.sessao.save(cidade);

}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Cidade> listar() {
    Criteria lista = sessao.createCriteria(Cidade.class); 
    return lista.list();
 }
}
```

**Segue erro do console**

```
Deu exceção 1: javax.servlet.ServletException:     javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
abr 13, 2016 9:21:49 PM   org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
1254927 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and    0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0   entities and 0 collections)
}
abr 13, 2016 9:21:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path     [/oneTrade] threw exception [null] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at     oneTrade.util.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:48)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilt    erChain.java:240)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Se possível, coloca o erro que aparece no console.

Comment: Obrigado por responder adelmo00. Complementei no final do poste acim a o erro que aparece no console.

Comment: Algum atributo está null, é fato. Debuga seu código e verifica qual atributo do filter está null.

Comment: Adelmo00 o doFilter tem dois parâmetros (servletFilter e servlet Response), os dois possuem valores. Existem alguns atributos dentro dos dois parâmetros que estão nulos, por exemplo: no servletFilter os parâmeros: asyncContext, authType, cookies, event, localAddr, localName, parts, partsParseException, postData, remoteAddr, remoteHost, subject  e userPrincipal estão nulos. Não sei se foi isso que você quis dizer.

Comment: É nessa linha que ocorre o erro:  chain.doFilter(servletFilter, servletResponse); //passa o filter e o response para o filter chain ??

Comment: Adelmo, realmente é nesta linha que está ocorrendo o problemas, porém não sei porque o erro ocorre. Já debuguei o método doFilter e não consegui encontrar o problema.